# Matcher group() function returns null

Tags: java, matcher

I have this regular expression `"([0-9TA])?(\\d{4})?([A-Z]{3})?"` and the string `"52021CCC"`.

```
String testNumber = "52021CCC";
String[] parts = null;

String regex = "([0-9TA])?(\\d{4})?([A-Z]{3})?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testNumber);
if (matcher.matches() || matcher.find()) {
    parts = new String[3];
    parts[0] = matcher.group(1);
    parts[1] = matcher.group(2);
    parts[2] = matcher.group(3);
    System.out.println(parts[0]);
    System.out.println(parts[1]);
    System.out.println(parts[2]);
}
```

I expected to print : 5, 2021, CCC

but it prints null, null, null.

When I change the input string to 5T2021CCC, it prints: T, 2021, CCC

My question is, since the first group is a single digit or the charaters T or A shouldnt the 52021CCC be matched and printed correctly?

I cannot understand where is the problem here.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ I m thinking your first group is a greedy expression meaning it captures all the digits and there is nothing left to match 2nd group, thus it is not a match overall

Comment: `matcher.matches()` would work fine. Did you just make an error by using a wrong text variable? You have `String testNumber = "52021CCC";` defined, but you are using `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(celexNumber)`, with `celexNumber` as the input.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, the input is testNumber

Comment: I m thinking, can you try replacing `\\d` with `[0-9]`? its basically the same, but its possible that by using \\d you escape the escape and it searches for literally \d

Comment: `matcher.find()` is not executed because `matcher.matches()` returns true and the expression short-circuits because of the `||`.

Comment: Also, if you add the missing `)` after `matcher.find()`, [your code will work fine](https://ideone.com/VstRaS). Still looks like a typo to me. The error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Yeah, no clue why this doesn't work in my environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the expression in the `if`:

```
if (matcher.matches() || matcher.find()) {
```

Since `matcher.matches()` returns true and this is a logical `or`, this expression short-circuits and the `matcher.find()` is never executed. This, all calls to `group()` will return `null`.

A simple fix is to replace the `or` with an `and`:

```
if (matcher.matches() && matcher.find()) {
```

In this case it might actually be enough to only call `find` and remove the `matches` check.

Comment: Tried everything, same output. As Wiktor said above, it should work with both conditions. Maybe I need to change the regex.

Comment: Did you save the file? Wiktor proved that the code works. That means that you are not running the code you think you are running.